# Installing Nest Thermostat 3rd Gen with Power Adapter to Honeywell HZ311 Zone Controller

Tags: wiring, hvac, nest

I’m attempting to hook up my Nest 3rd Gen thermostat to my zone controller and everything appeared to be working correctly.

However, after turning the system back on and cycling through heat and cold, the indicator for Zone 2 started blinking orange and the dampener turned off.

It appears that blinking orange indicates a power issue with the dampener.

The Nest displays some errors and with the power adapter, its not charging, even with the addition of the C-wire.

Any thoughts on what I may have incorrectly wired up?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]